# Linq query to filter dictionary from list

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to filter a dictionary with a list but though there are matching items the result is empty.

What's wrong with my code?

```
String.Join(",", dict.Where(Function(x) aList.Contains(x.Key)).Select(Function(y) y.Key))
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample data where you expect a match but don't get one? Note that it will be case-sensitive.

Comment: What a nightmare! I coded an example so i could post it here. And it works perfectly fine. I am doing the exact same thing in my code. The case is ok in this case as its in UPPER both the objects being compared. SMH.